# Japanese Scoring System on Public High School Examinations: Quintessential Quintuplets season 2

Tags: culture, japan, the-quintessential-quintuplets

In *5 Toubun no Hanayome*, Fuutarou is assigned to help a rich businessman's quintuplet daughters pass their examinations and graduate. Unfortunately, they all suck at academics, or get distracted by other activities and career goals. Fuutarou notices that each one excels at a different subject, so he tries to leverage that fact to everyone's advantage so that each quintuplet can elevate the others in their subject of expertise.

They tend to fail in the first season, regardless, but by S2 E6, they get passing scores, like the image below:

[image]

**How are passing grades determined in Japanese high schools?** In America, marks below 60, or even 70 in some districts, are considered a failing grade, but somehow a 38 in one of the subjects is good enough for an overall passing grade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *The Quintessential Quintuplets*, **the passing grade is 30 or above per subject.**

This was inferred and stated in the midterm exam's result (chapter 20), when

- Yotsuba said that she failed all subjects except National Language with 30.
- Miku said that she only passed Social Sciences and failed the rest, even Maths with 29.

  [image]
- Fuutarou was disappointed because the girls failed to get 30 points after studying hard for a short period.

  [image]

---

In Japan, the general passing grade is also 30 points, though it may also depend on the school policy:

- There are schools with 20, 40, or even 60 passing grade
- Some schools use the average score of the subject instead, or half of it

---

References:

- manga-games.com, a Japanese blog for chapter summary

  - [Chapter 49](https://manga-games.com/gotobunnohanayome-magajin-49/)
  - [Volume 3](https://manga-games.com/gotobunnohanayome-vol-3/)
- [Yahoo! Chiebukuro - What is the failing grade for tests (in high school)?](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1341203383) (Japanese)